# Obtain list of newer releases in docker

Tags: docker

Is there a docker command to get the list of versions (images) from the repo that are newer than the one currently running on the system? For instance, the system is running 2.6, and the repo hosts newer releases viz., ( 2.6.5, 2.7, 2.7.3, 2.9 ).

This is to be able to do an incremental upgrade when upgrading between major versions, say from 2.6 to 2.9 is not supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output

`To list all images with their repository and tag in a table format you can use:
$ docker images --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Repository}}\t{{.Tag}}"
IMAGE ID            REPOSITORY                TAG
77af4d6b9913        <none>                    <none>
b6fa739cedf5        committ                   latest
78a85c484f71        <none>                    <none>
30557a29d5ab        docker                    latest
5ed6274db6ce        <none>                    <none>
746b819f315e        postgres                  9
746b819f315e        postgres                  9.3
746b819f315e        postgres                  9.3.5
746b819f315e        postgres                  latest`

Another way to go is using the registry, like in this answer

[How can I determine if a specific tag is available for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437885/how-can-i-determine-if-a-specific-tag-is-available-for-an-image)

By the way, be careful about the tag latest, it is just a name

https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375

See also

http://www.googlinux.com/list-all-tags-of-docker-image/index.html

Comment: This lists the images already downloaded on the system. I want to be able to query the remote server to get this information.

Comment: So use the first link, use the API, launch `tags_json=$(curl "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/${repo}/${image}/tags/${version}/" 2>/dev/null)
tags_found="$(echo "${tags_json}" | jq ".v2?")"`

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker search <reponame>`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/